# How to provide a password to the redigo client in redisearch-go (Golang)

Tags: go, redis, redigo, redisearch

I'm trying to use Go to connect to my RediSearch (Redis module) instance.

Combing through the documentation and Go code that generates the client, I don't see how to pass authentication options to the Redigo client within... Is this an oversight on my part or are we just expected to use RediSearch without securing the database?

I've also tried the following when generating a RediSearch client. Each gives errors regarding the format of the URL:

```
redisearch.NewClient("mypasswordhere@10.10.10.50:6379", index)
redisearch.NewClient("redis://mypasswordhere@10.10.10.50:6379", index)
```

Within `pool.go`, in the `NewSingleHostPool` function that returns a client, it seems like it should pass `DialOptions` into the `Dial` Redigo function instead of `nil`, and have those options be passed into the RediSearch `NewClient` function...

Comment: Send the [AUTH command](https://redis.io/commands/auth) after dialing.

Answer (score 2):

Call [NewClientWithPool](https://godoc.org/github.com/RediSearch/redisearch-go/redisearch#NewClientFromPool) with a [pool dial function](https://godoc.org/github.com/gomodule/redigo/redis#Pool.Dial) of your choice.

```
p := &redis.Pool{
    Dial: func() (*Conn, error) { 
       return redis.DialURL("redis://mypasswordhere@10.10.10.50:6379") 
    },
    MaxIdle: 3,                     // adjust to taste 
    IdleTimeout: 240 * time.Second, // adjust to taste

}
c := redissearch.NewClientFromPool(p, index)
```

Answer (score 2):

A nice way to do this is like so, with built-in constructs for password auth by redigo:

```
func newPool(server string, password string) *redis.Pool {
    return &redis.Pool{
        MaxIdle:     3,
        IdleTimeout: 240 * time.Second,
        Dial: func() (redis.Conn, error) {
            return redis.Dial("tcp",
                server,
                redis.DialPassword(password))
        },

        TestOnBorrow: func(c redis.Conn, t time.Time) error {
            _, err := c.Do("PING")
            return err
        },
    }
}
```

Your `server` should look like this: `redis-1344.333.us-east-1-mz.ec2.com:17885` and the password is plain text.